# In CreateFile() what is the quickest way to assign Read-Only permissions to the standard user Everybody. And no permissions to anyone else

Tags: winapi, acl, ntfs, dacl

In Windows, I have an application that needs to set the access control to the user/group 'Everybody' only. And sets permissions to Read-Only. Under Linux a Simple `open()` call with octal `004` permissions is sufficient. On Windows, how do I accomplish the same thing? Preferably in the call to `CreateFile()`.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use the read-only attribute?

Comment: What object are you wanting to secure? I can't discern that from your question?

Comment: Gabe this is a backup application; I need to be sure the files are world-readable and not associated with any particular user. Write protection for added safety. @David I am trying to secure standard files on an NTFS volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the proper attributes.  The functions linked to from there are a good starting point for creating the proper security descriptor (it's far from trivial).  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows a good example of creating one, including how to get the SID for the "Everybody" group (`pEveryoneSID` in the code).

Then, just pass in that security descriptor to `CreateFile` as the `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter.

Comment: I recommend to use ATL wrappers: CSid, CAcl, CDacl, CSacl, CSecurityDesc, CSecurityAttributes. The code will be much cleaner.